# Tkinter, enable maximize button when resizable is False

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

Is there a way to enable maximize button, when I have:

```
app.resizable(width=False, height=False)
```

I want just two states of a window, fixed size and maximized(fullscreen with a title)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to enable the maximize button when you set `resizable` to false. Generally speaking, you have no control over those buttons at all. You provide hints to the os/window manager such as with the `resizeable` attribute and `overrideredirect` method, but ultimately the OS/window manager decides what to put in the titlebar.

Personally I recommend to never set `resizable` to false. I think it gives a bad user experience. The user knows better than I do what size they need a window to be. Maybe they have a monitor with a different resolution than me? Different fonts? Better eyesight? Worse eyesight?